# Cleaning Up EEO-1 Data: How do I account for complex table types with multiple rows of headers as I convert from a PDF to CSV?

Tags: excel, csv, pdf, adobe, ocr

[image: 1]'
Link to data: https://diversity.fb.com/read-report/ (2019 EEO-1 Report)

I'm dealing with a table such as the one above. I managed to get the tables rows and columns to convert accurately to the Excel file. However, as I move forward with data analysis, I'm wondering how I can get rid of the table's complex headings so I could just have one row of headings to easily convert this to a CSV. I'm planning to go through several hundred of these types of PDFs (with identical table structures, differing table values obviously), so if I could also create some sort of template to map each of these PDFs to as it converts them, that would be great.

Is there any way I can automate this process without completely having to go by hand? Or is the nature of the way these documents are structured going to force me to go through it completely by hand? Thanks in advance.

I tried a plethora of PDF to CSV conversion methods, but I settled with Adobe, because it transferred them all accurately. But now that I'm looking at the table, I'm realizing I don't want to preserve some of its structure, because I don't think it'll be easy for me to analyze as I start to move towards data analysis and visualization.

Or perhaps there's something with OCR I could do?

Comment: could you add the URL of a sample PDF source?

Comment: @aborruso https://diversity.fb.com/read-report/ . The report is called 2019 EEO-1 Report! Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest post processing the report in Excel using vba, to reduce it to a format compatible with csv.  How complex that is will depend on how much variation there is in the generated report sheets.  To offer any detailed advice I'd need to see an example of the required output (csv layout)

Comment: @chrisneilsen Hi, thanks for your help! The idea is that I will be doing analysis on the data and forming visualizations to map out certain genders by job category, ethnicity by job category, etc. I'm a bit of a beginner, so I'm wondering if you have any insight on how this can best be achieved in terms of laying out the CSV for easy data analysis as we proceed to use VBA?

Comment: Re _I'm wondering if you have any insight on how this can best be achieved in terms of laying out the CSV for easy data analysis_ I have no idea what you are trying to analyze,  or even why csv is the target format.  Any answer I gave would be pure speculation,  and therefore not useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tabula](https://tabula.technology/), and extract first the data, and then the header.
You can save your procedures as scripts.

[image]

And you can use Excel

[image]

And if you want you can customize and save your extraction query

[image]